# How to find the Xpath of <Td> tag from text which lie under <a> tag of that <td> in selenium c#

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#

I have to find text on a page, which I did. Now I need to find the xpath of the `<td>` element containing that text so that I can use the `<td>` xpath to find other elements like the image button and the delete button.

Image Description: This image contains one `<Td>` in which there is one `<a>` tag which contains text, i.e. Automation Testing, so first I have to find the text and then find the xpath of the `<td>`. The `<a>` tag contains an id attribute but this id changes dynamically according to the user input so I cannot find `<a>` tag with id.

[image: Html]

Comment: Have you tried using CroPath? Mark Smith.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually easier than it sounds.

First, unless you need to click the `<a>` link, you can retrieve the `<td>` element with the following:

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//td[contains(., 'Automation Testing')]"));
```

Alternatively, if you need the `<a>` link, you can find the immediate parent (the `<td>` element with:

```
IWebElement element = linkElement.FindElement(By.Xpath("./.."));
```

From there the image buttons can be retrieved with linq-style queries (you will need to make sure you have `using System.Linq;` in your usings. `element` is the `<td>` element, which will make sure that your code doesn't retrieve anything outside your target table cell.

```
List<IWebElement> elements = element.FindElements(By.TagName("img"));

IWebElement addChild = elements.Where(el => el.GetAttribute("Title") == "Add Child");
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code, hope it helps.

//to find the image with title = Add Child

```
IWebElement element = 
driver.FindElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Automation')]/following-sibling::* 
[1]");
```

//to find the image button with title = Delete

```
IWebElement element = 
driver.FindElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Automation')]/following-sibling::* 
[3]");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with absolute Xpath this is an example: `/td[a[@href='url-a']]/following-sibling::td[1]/a/text()`